# RxJava 2 - Reduce queue in concatMap

Tags: java, android, queue, rx-java2, concatmap

I have a subject that emits some data. Then I want to modify this data in the queue (long operation). But when another subject will emit other things I want to reduce my queue

```
    PublishSubject<Integer> myBaseSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    PublishSubject<Integer> otherSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    myBaseSubject
            .concatMap(integer -> Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // long operation
                    .map(aLong -> integer)
            )
            .subscribe(
                    integer -> Log.i(TAG, "result: " + integer),
                    Functions.emptyConsumer()
            );

    myBaseSubject.onNext(1);
    myBaseSubject.onNext(2);
    myBaseSubject.onNext(3);
    myBaseSubject.onNext(4); 
    myBaseSubject.onNext(5);

    otherSubject.onNext(3);
    otherSubject.onNext(4);

    myBaseSubject.onNext(6);
    myBaseSubject.onNext(7);
```

Now I want to modify my disposable to skip elements emited by `otherSubject` (3 and 4) if those elements aren't already consumed by `concatMap`(they are still in queue).

Is it possible to achieve that?

PS: PublishSubject is not required - it's used just for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `ConcurrentHashMap` to track which elements should be not processed by `concatMap`. I'm assuming the decision to not process an item happens after that item's index has been created.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

myBaseSubject
    .doOnNext(v  -> map.put(v, v))
    .concatMap(integer -> {
        if (map.remove(integer) != null) {
            return Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // long operation
                .map(aLong -> integer)
        }
        return Observable.empty();
    })
    .subscribe(
        integer -> Log.i(TAG, "result: " + integer),
        Functions.emptyConsumer()
    );

myBaseSubject.onNext(1);
myBaseSubject.onNext(2);
myBaseSubject.onNext(3);
myBaseSubject.onNext(4); 
myBaseSubject.onNext(5);

map.remove(3);
map.remove(4);

myBaseSubject.onNext(6);
myBaseSubject.onNext(7);
```